# How to set conditions for filling specific gaps in panel data?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, time-series, missing-data

I have panel data in an R data.frame containing years from 1989-2008 for armed conflicts in various countries. However, only observations for countries which experienced armed conflict in a given year are included.

The dataset is similar to this:

```
df <- data.frame(c("1989","1993","1998",
     "1990","1995","1997"),
    c(rep(c(750, 135), c(3,3))), c(rep(1,6)))
names(df)<-c("year","countrycode","conflict")
print(df)

  year countrycode conflict
1 1989         750        1
2 1993         750        1
3 1998         750        1
4 1990         135        1
5 1995         135        1
6 1997         135        1
```

I now want to fill gaps in the panel data, BUT ONLY gaps which are not bigger than three years. For example, I want add rows between rows 1 and 2 and between rows 5 and 7 (the gap is 3 and 1 year respectively), but neither between rows 2 and 3 nor between rows 4 and 5 (the gaps is 4 years each). After this procedure, the data.frame above would look the following:

```
> df2 <- data.frame(c("1989","1990","1991","1992","1993","1998",
+      "1990","1995","1996","1997"),
+     c(rep(c(750, 135), c(6,4))), c(1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1))
> names(df2) <- c("year","countrycode","conflict")
> print(df2)
   year countrycode conflict
1  1989         750        1
2  1990         750        0
3  1991         750        0
4  1992         750        0
5  1993         750        1
6  1998         750        1
7  1990         135        1
8  1995         135        1
9  1996         135        0
10 1997         135        1
```

I have looked into the `plm` package (see [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/plm.pdf)), but couldn't find any answer there. Also, I am relatively new to R, so I'll be happy for any hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using `data.table`. The idea is to first create a `data.table` with just the missing entries `(dt.rest)` and then `rbind` them. I've written it in such a way that the output of each line (by copy/pasting and printing) should be fairly straightforward to follow. Let me know if something isn't clear.

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df, key="countrycode")
dt$year <- as.numeric(as.character(dt$year))
dt[J(unique(countrycode)), year2 := c(tail(year, -1), NA)]
dt.rest <- dt[, { tt <- which(year2-year-1 <=3); 
                  list(year = unlist(lapply(tt, function(x) 
                              seq(year[x]+1, year2[x]-1, by=1))), 
                       conflict = 0)
                }, by=countrycode]
setcolorder(dt.rest, c("year", "countrycode", "conflict"))

#    year countrycode conflict
# 1: 1996         135        0
# 2: 1990         750        0
# 3: 1991         750        0
# 4: 1992         750        0
```

Now, we just have to `rbind` them. This is done using `rbindlist` function within `data.table` that binds `data.frame` or `data.table` much more efficiently than `rbind`.

```
dt[, year2 := NULL]
dt <- rbindlist(list(dt, dt.rest))
setkey(dt, "countrycode", "year")

dt
#     year countrycode conflict
#  1: 1990         135        1
#  2: 1995         135        1
#  3: 1996         135        0
#  4: 1997         135        1
#  5: 1989         750        1
#  6: 1990         750        0
#  7: 1991         750        0
#  8: 1992         750        0
#  9: 1993         750        1
# 10: 1998         750        1
```

Comment: Slick solution and good point making sure `df$year` is a number and not a factor. Mine was already integer so I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

This solution might seem messy and hard to digest for a beginner, but since it is a very specific and unusual problem (to me at least) I can't come up with anything more basic.

```
# Convert the `year` column to integer in case it is a factor
df$year <- as.integer(as.character(df$year))

df.country <- lapply(
    # Split `df` by `countrycode` to make one data frame per country
    split(df, df$countrycode),

    # Apply the following function to each coutry's data frame
    function(tab){
        # Send the start and end years of each gap to the following function
        imputed.yr <- mapply(function(start, end)
            # If the gap is small enough add all values in between
            # otherwise just return the start and end years
            if(end - start < 5) start:end else c(start, end),
        tab$year[-nrow(tab)], tab$year[-1])

        # Remove duplicate years
        imputed.yr <- unique(unlist(imputed.yr))
        # Pack up and return a new data frame
        data.frame(year = imputed.yr,
                   contrycode = tab$countrycode[1],
                   conflict = imputed.yr %in% tab$year)
    })

# Paste all the imputed country specific data frames together
do.call(rbind, df.country)
```

The above code produces the following output, which is essentially the same as what you asked for.

```
      year contrycode conflict
135.1 1990        135     TRUE
135.2 1995        135     TRUE
135.3 1996        135    FALSE
135.4 1997        135     TRUE
750.1 1989        750     TRUE
750.2 1990        750    FALSE
750.3 1991        750    FALSE
750.4 1992        750    FALSE
750.5 1993        750     TRUE
750.6 1998        750     TRUE
```

Comment: (+1) @Backlin, right the problem is specific. AnneroseN, just multiply `conflict` by 1 to get 1 and 0 instead of TRUE/FALSE.

Comment: @Backlin, there seems to be some error in the code you suggested that I don't manage to fix. I get the following error message: `Error in if (end - start < 4) start:end else c(start, end) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(end, start) : - not meaningful for factors`  -- Do you have some idea how I could fix it?

Comment: I assume the data you show is just a part of your dataset and you get the error when you run it on the whole. The problem is that there are missing values in the `year` column. You could remove all such rows with `df <- df[!is.na(df$year),]`, but you should probably check them out manually first to make sure there is nothing wrong with your data.